# GRE debug: "adding 0 encap bytes"?

Tags: debugging, gre

What this debug message actually means? Shouldn't encapsulation add 24 extra bytes or not? For what reason encapsulation is not adding bytes to original packet in this debug message?

`Dec 28 23:45:39.303: Tunnel0: GRE/IP encapsulated 10.0.0.1->10.0.0.2 (linktype=7, len=124)`

`Dec 28 23:45:39.303: Tunnel0 count tx, adding 0 encap bytes`

Comment: It's Cisco 1941 router in the question.